# Is it possible to "Archive" Firebase records

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have an Android `ListView` which displays data from my Firebase database. When I click on a data record in my `ListView` an `Alert Dialog` appears with and Archive `Button`.

I want a selected record to be transferred to another `ListView` in another activity within my application, i.e. "archived".

I know this will mean creating an `archive` node for my Firebase database.

Below is the method for bring up my `Alert Dialog`, which includes a `Button` to carry out my method `archiveMaintenance`. I'm stuck however, as to where to start on what to put in `archiveMaintenance`.

**`showProgressDialog`**

```
private void showProgressDialog(final String id, String title, String description, String property, String maintenanceTitle) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.archive_maintenance, null);

    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final Spinner spinnerProgress = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerProgress);
    final Button buttonUpdateProgress = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateProgress);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Maintenance: " + maintenanceTitle);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    buttonUpdateProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
            String desc = editTextDesc.getText().toString().trim();

            String progress = spinnerProgress.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String property = spinnerProperty.getSelectedItem().toString();

            updateProgress(title, desc, id, property, progress);

            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    buttonUpdateArchive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            archiveMaintenance(id);
        }
    });

}
```

**`archivedMaintenance`**

```
private void archiveMaintenance(String id) {

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference recordsRef = rootRef.child("maintenance");
        DatabaseReference recordIdRef = recordsRef.child(id);
        DatabaseReference archivedRecordsRef = rootRef.child("archive");
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                MaintenanceList maintenanceList = dataSnapshot.getValue(MaintenanceList.class); //First step
                archivedRecordsRef.child(id).setValue(maintenanceList); //Second step
                dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue(); //Third step

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };

        recordIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    }
```

**`MaintenanceList`**

```
public class MaintenanceList extends ArrayAdapter<Maintenance> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<Maintenance> maintenanceList;

    public MaintenanceList(Activity context, List<Maintenance> maintenanceList) {

        super(context, R.layout.maintenance_list_layout, maintenanceList);
        this.context = context;
        this.maintenanceList = maintenanceList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maintenance_list_layout, null, true);

        TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        TextView textViewDesc = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
        TextView textViewProperty = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewProperty);
        TextView textViewProgress = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewProgress);

        Maintenance maintenance = maintenanceList.get(position);

        textViewTitle.setText(maintenance.getMaintenanceTitle());
        textViewDesc.setText(maintenance.getMaintenanceDescription());
        textViewProperty.setText(maintenance.getMaintenanceProperty());
        textViewProgress.setText(maintenance.getMaintenanceProgress());

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

I have created and activity with a `ListView` ready to take the data - `ArchiveList`.

Any thoughts/pointers on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the `archiveMaintenance(id)` method you need to add code that will help you move the record from a location to another. Let's assume you have a `records` node in which exist all your records and a `archivedRecords` node where exist all archived records. Assuming aso that you have a helper class that is named `RecordModel`, to move a record from a location to another, you need to follow the next steps:

1. get the record
2. add the record to new location
3. remove the record from the old location

Your method should look like this:

```
private void archiveMaintenance(String recordId) {
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference recordsRef = rootRef.child("records");
    DatabaseReference recordIdRef = recordsRef.child(recordId);
    DatabaseReference archivedRecordsRef = rootRef.child("archivedRecords");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            RecordModel recordModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(RecordModel.class); //First step
            archivedRecordsRef.child(recordId).setValue(recordModel); //Second step
            dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue(); //Third step
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    recordIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however, I'm unsure how to implement this helper class RecordModel. Can you give me a few pointers?

Comment: This is only an example. I assumed you already have used a model class to add data. I named it generically `RecordModel` but the real name is in your code. The class might also be the String class, if the value of the `recordId` key is a String.

Comment: I have added to my question `MaintenanceList` and my `archiveMaintenance` method. I am still very unsure about a few things. Do you mind if we go to chat to discuss further?

Comment: `MaintenanceList` is a class that extens `ArrayAdapter` class. I ment through `RecordModel`, the class that helps you add records to the database. You must use `Maintenance` class, as I understand this is your model class and not `MaintenanceList`.

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm still getting a few errors. Can you open a chat window and we can discuss? Do not want to clog the comments.

Comment: Ok, let's discuss on chat and tell what the errors are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168240/discussion-between-wright-arturo-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Is there everything alright? Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: I am still trying my best to implement.

Comment: I have got round the issues I was having, I have sent you a chat message regarding this.

Comment: Add it as a comment.

Comment: Add what as a comment sorry?

Comment: Just answered your question.